# Logic for displaying specific data from one point to another

Tags: logic

Logic for displaying specific data from one point to another.

Expected Output:

```
12:00:00 - 13:00:00 -> should display 1 (In the log, timestamp 12:00:00 has data as "1", All lines from 12:00:00 until 13:00:00 should display 1. But has to change at 13:00:00, as timestamp 13:00:00 has new data which is "5")
13:00:00 - 14:00:00 -> should display 5 (13:00:00 line has data as 5)
14:00:00 - 15:00:00 -> should display 7 (14:00:00 line has data as 7)
```

Code that is used currently:

```
eachTBData.TimeStamp >= this.x
```

And the current Output:

```
 Correct data is not shown (Maps and displays in the previous set instead)
 12:00:00 - 13:00:00  -> this set displays 5 (has to display 1)
 13:00:00 - 14:00:00 -> this set displays 7 (has to display 5)
```

Tried:

```
Thought using '<= this.x' instead of '>= this.x' as shown in below line, would solve the issue. 
But does not work and displays the initial data "1" for all sets:

    eachTBData.TimeStamp <= this.x
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try following which uses Regex

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            string line = "";
            string pattern = @"""(?'key1'[^""]+)"":""(?'data'\d+)"",""(?'key2'[^""]+)"":""(?'time'[^""]+)";
            string oldData = "";
            string time = "";
            string oldTime = "";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    string key1 = match.Groups["key1"].Value;
                    time = match.Groups["time"].Value;
                    if (key1 == "data")
                    {
                        string data = match.Groups["data"].Value;
                        if (data != oldData)
                        {
                            if (oldData.Length != 0)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} -> {2}", oldTime, time, oldData);
                            }
                            oldData = data;
                            oldTime = time;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} -> {2}", oldTime, time, oldData);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, will there be a simpler solution? With this condition checking  "eachTBData.TimeStamp >= this.x", I am able to apply specific data for each past sets but not upcoming sets. I need to find a way to apply for upcoming sets.

Comment: You need a state machine and keep track of old and latest values.  You also need to process first and last sample different from the rest.  Your code didn't work so you need something more complicated.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use your code as example.